# OpenAI Gym Minecraft Environment First Run Fail

Tags: minecraft

I am trying to build an OpenAI Minecraft environment and everything worked fine until I try to test the environment with given code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
import minecraft_py
proc, port = minecraft_py.start()
minecraft_py.stop(proc)
```

However, it failed printing the following message when running the above testing code.
Please help...

```
INFO:minecraft_py:Starting Minecraft process: /home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/launchClient.sh -port 10000
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'****************************\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' Powered By MCP:             \n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' http://modcoderpack.com/    \n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r, \n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' MCP Data version : 9.10\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'****************************\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b"Version string 'unspecified' does not match SemVer specification \n"
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'You should try SemVer : http://semver.org/\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':deobfCompileDummyTask\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':deobfProvidedDummyTask\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':getVersionJson\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':extractUserdev UP-TO-DATE\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':extractMcpData SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':extractMcpMappings SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':genSrgs SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':downloadClient SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':downloadServer SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':splitServerJar SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':mergeJars SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':deobfMcSRG SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':getFernFlower SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':decompileMc SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':fixMcSources SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':applySourcePatches SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':remapMcSources SKIPPED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':recompileMc\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'[ant:javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'[ant:javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'[ant:javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'[ant:javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'[ant:javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'[ant:javac] 1 warning\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':recompileMc FAILED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'* What went wrong:\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b"Execution failed for task ':recompileMc'.\n"
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'> Problems opening file input stream for file: /home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/tmp/recompileMc/compiled/net/minecraft/network/play/server/S14PacketEntity$S16PacketEntityLook.class\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'* Try:\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'BUILD FAILED\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'Total time: 35.219 secs\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'****************************\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' Powered By MCP:             \n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' http://modcoderpack.com/    \n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r, \n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b' MCP Data version : 9.10\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'****************************\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b"Version string 'unspecified' does not match SemVer specification \n"
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'You should try SemVer : http://semver.org/\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':deobfCompileDummyTask\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':deobfProvidedDummyTask\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':compileApiJava UP-TO-DATE\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':processApiResources UP-TO-DATE\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':apiClasses UP-TO-DATE\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':copyModToClient UP-TO-DATE\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':copyModToServer UP-TO-DATE\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':deleteSchemas\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':copySchemas\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':jaxb UP-TO-DATE\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':sourceMainJava UP-TO-DATE\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b':compileJavaerror: error reading /home/alexzhou/.gradle/caches/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.8-11.14.3.1543/snapshot/20141130/forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.3.1543.jar; error in opening zip file\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'error: error reading /home/alexzhou/.gradle/caches/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.8-11.14.3.1543/snapshot/20141130/forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.3.1543.jar; cannot read zip file\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:24: error: package net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living.LivingDeathEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                             ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:25: error: package net.minecraftforge.event.world does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.event.world.ChunkEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                     ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:26: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.client.event.ConfigChangedEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.event.ConfigChangedEvent.OnConfigChangedEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                             ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:27: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                 ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:28: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.PlayerEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.PlayerEvent.PlayerLoggedInEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                          ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:29: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                              ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:22: error: package net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living.LivingDeathEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                             ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:23: error: package net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living.LivingSpawnEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living.LivingSpawnEvent.CheckSpawn;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                              ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:24: error: package net.minecraftforge.event.world does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.event.world.ChunkEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                     ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:25: error: package net.minecraftforge.event.world.WorldEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.event.world.WorldEvent.PotentialSpawns;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:26: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.client.event.ConfigChangedEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.event.ConfigChangedEvent.OnConfigChangedEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                             ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:27: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.PlayerEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.PlayerEvent.PlayerLoggedInEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                          ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:28: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent.ClientTickEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                        ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:29: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent.PlayerTickEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                        ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:30: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent.RenderTickEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                        ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:31: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent.ServerTickEvent;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                        ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:60: error: package TickEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    public void onClientTick(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent ev)\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                      ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:79: error: package TickEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    public void onServerTick(TickEvent.ServerTickEvent ev)\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                      ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:91: error: package TickEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    public void onPlayerTick(TickEvent.PlayerTickEvent ev)\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                      ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:103: error: package TickEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    public void onRenderTick(TickEvent.RenderTickEvent ev)\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                      ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:115: error: package ChunkEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    public void onChunkLoad(ChunkEvent.Load cev)\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                      ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:127: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    public void onPlayerDies(LivingDeathEvent lde)\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                             ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class LivingDeathEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class EpisodeEventWrapper\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:139: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    public void onConfigChanged(OnConfigChangedEvent ev)\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class OnConfigChangedEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class EpisodeEventWrapper\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/EpisodeEventWrapper.java:157: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    public void onPlayerJoinedServer(PlayerLoggedInEvent ev)\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                     ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class PlayerLoggedInEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class EpisodeEventWrapper\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateMachine.java:24: error: package net.minecraftforge.common does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateMachine.java:25: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.common does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                    ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:95: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    protected void onClientTick(ClientTickEvent ev) throws Exception {}\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class ClientTickEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class StateEpisode\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:97: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    protected void onServerTick(ServerTickEvent ev) {}\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class ServerTickEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class StateEpisode\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:99: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    protected void onPlayerTick(PlayerTickEvent ev) {}\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class PlayerTickEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class StateEpisode\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:101: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    protected void onRenderTick(RenderTickEvent ev) {}\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class RenderTickEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class StateEpisode\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:103: error: package ChunkEvent does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    protected void onChunkLoad(ChunkEvent.Load cev) {}\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                         ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:105: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    protected void onPlayerDies(LivingDeathEvent event) {}\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class LivingDeathEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class StateEpisode\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:107: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    protected void onConfigChanged(OnConfigChangedEvent event) {}\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                   ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class OnConfigChangedEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class StateEpisode\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/StateEpisode.java:109: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    protected void onPlayerJoinedServer(PlayerLoggedInEvent event) {}\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                        ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class PlayerLoggedInEvent\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class StateEpisode\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoAuthenticationScreen.java:26: error: package net.minecraft.client.gui does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiButton;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                               ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoAuthenticationScreen.java:27: error: package net.minecraft.client.gui does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                               ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoAuthenticationScreen.java:28: error: package net.minecraft.client.gui does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiTextField;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                               ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoAuthenticationScreen.java:29: error: package net.minecraft.util does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.util.EnumChatFormatting;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                         ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoAuthenticationScreen.java:30: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.client.config does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.config.GuiButtonExt;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                           ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:26: error: package net.minecraft.client does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                           ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:27: error: package net.minecraft.client.gui does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiButton;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                               ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:28: error: package net.minecraft.client.gui does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                               ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:29: error: package net.minecraftforge.common.config does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.common.config.ConfigCategory;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                       ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:30: error: package net.minecraftforge.common.config does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.common.config.ConfigElement;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                       ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:31: error: package net.minecraftforge.common.config does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.common.config.Property;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                       ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:32: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.client does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.IModGuiFactory;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                    ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:33: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.client.config does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.config.GuiButtonExt;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                           ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:34: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.client.config does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.config.GuiConfig;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                           ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:35: error: package net.minecraftforge.fml.client.config does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.config.IConfigElement;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                           ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:40: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'public class MalmoModGuiOptions implements IModGuiFactory\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                           ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol: class IModGuiFactory\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoAuthenticationScreen.java:39: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'public class MalmoAuthenticationScreen extends GuiScreen\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                               ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol: class GuiScreen\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoModGuiOptions.java:42: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    public static class MalmoModGuiScreen extends GuiConfig\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                                  ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class GuiConfig\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class MalmoModGuiOptions\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/Utils/AuthenticationHelper.java:26: error: package net.minecraft.client does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                           ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/Utils/AuthenticationHelper.java:27: error: package net.minecraft.client.resources does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.client.resources.I18n;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                     ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/Utils/AuthenticationHelper.java:29: error: package net.minecraft.util does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraft.util.Session;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                         ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/Utils/AuthenticationHelper.java:30: error: package net.minecraftforge.common.config does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.common.config.Configuration;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                       ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/Utils/AuthenticationHelper.java:31: error: package net.minecraftforge.common.config does not exist\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'import net.minecraftforge.common.config.Property;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'                                       ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoAuthenticationScreen.java:44: error: cannot find symbol\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'    private GuiTextField usernameField;\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'            ^\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  symbol:   class GuiTextField\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'  location: class MalmoAuthenticationScreen\n'
DEBUG:minecraft_py:b'/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/Malmo/Minecraft/build/sources/main/java/com/microsoft/Malmo/MalmoAuthenticationScreen.java:45: error: cannot find symbol\n'
...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/alexzhou/minecraft-py35-ubuntu1604/minecraft_py/__init__.py", line 63, in start
        raise EOFError("Minecraft process finished unexpectedly")
    EOFError: Minecraft process finished unexpectedly
```

The installation is perfectly fine but something went wrong in the process of running the code above. I used the prebuilt minecraft_py version for py35.